# probnorm function equivalent in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sas

PROBNORM : explanation

The PROBNORM function in SAS returns the probability that an observation from the standard normal distribution is less than or equal to x.

Is there any equivalent function in pyspark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that in PySpark there is no such implemented method.
However, you can exploit [Pandas UDFs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/arrow_pandas.html#pandas-udfs-a-k-a-vectorized-udfs) to define your own custom function using basic Python packages! Here we are going to use [`scipy.stats.norm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html) module to get cumulative probabilities from a standard normal distribution.

Versions I'm using:

- `Spark 3.1.1`
- `pandas 1.1.5`
- `scipy 1.5.2`

**Example code**

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import norm
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf


# create sample data
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 0.00),
    (2, -1.23),
    (3, 4.56),
], ['id', 'value'])


# define your custom Pandas UDF
@pandas_udf('double')
def probnorm(s: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return pd.Series(norm.cdf(s))


# create a new column using the Pandas UDF
df = df.withColumn('pnorm', probnorm(F.col('value')))


df.show()

+---+-----+-------------------+
| id|value|              pnorm|
+---+-----+-------------------+
|  1|  0.0|                0.5|
|  2|-1.23|0.10934855242569191|
|  3| 4.56| 0.9999974423189606|
+---+-----+-------------------+
```

---

### Edit

If you do not have `scipy` properly installed on your workers too, you can use the Python base package `math` and a little bit of [statistics knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

```
import math
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def normal_cdf(x, mu=0, sigma=1):
    """
    Cumulative distribution function for the normal distribution
    with mean `mu` and standard deviation `sigma`
    """
    return (1 + math.erf((x - mu) / (sigma * math.sqrt(2)))) / 2

my_udf = udf(normal_cdf)

df = df.withColumn('pnorm', my_udf(F.col('value')))

df.show()

+---+-----+-------------------+
| id|value|              pnorm|
+---+-----+-------------------+
|  1|  0.0|                0.5|
|  2|-1.23|0.10934855242569197|
|  3| 4.56| 0.9999974423189606|
+---+-----+-------------------+
```

Results are in fact the same.

Comment: I get error mess : ImportError: PyArrow >= 0.8.0 must be installed;...is there any way to make ppf function work as I do not have the privileges to install pyArrow

Comment: One attempt you can try, although I'm not very confident: `norm_cdf = F.udf(lambda x: float(norm.cdf(x))); df = df.withColumn('pnorm', norm_cdf(F.col('value')))`

Comment: STill no luck : Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1689.showString.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'

Comment: def probnorm(s: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return pd.Series(norm.cdf(s))  this part throws PyArrow error...if I just use norm_cdf = F.udf(lambda x: float(norm.cdf(x))) I get scipy error

Comment: I have scipy version 1.2

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'` means that Python wasn't able to import scipy in some machines. My hypothesis is that you installed scipy only in the main Spark driver, but you need to install scipy (and other relevant packages) on the workers too

Comment: @AmyJack If you don't have the opportunity to properly install scipy on the workers, I edited my answer with another possible solution. I hope you should be able to run this as the `math` package is a basic one for Python, so it should be installed on your workers as well.

Comment: It worked...Thank u so much.....Ill try and find a formula for probit function as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235615/discussion-between-amy-jack-and-ric-s).

Comment: Can u kindly  help me with the math for probit function . https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/statug/15.2/statug_probit_overview.htm....

Comment: I'm sorry but this is a website for coding questions. For maths, check out [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I will look into the website. I was looking for code for probit like ((1 + math.erf((x - mu) / (sigma * math.sqrt(2)))) / 2).... I have tried below logic; the values do not align with SAS values def normpdf(x, mu, sigma):
    u = (x-mu)/abs(sigma)
    y = (1/(sqrt(2*pi)*abs(sigma)))*exp(-u*u/2)
    return y...

Comment: I also tried def normpdf(x, mean, sd):
    var = float(sd)**2
    denom = (2*math.pi*var)**.5
    num = math.exp(-(float(x)-float(mean))**2/(2*var))
    return num/denom.......normpdf(0.008,0,1) 
0.3989295144527161 instead of -2.408915546..........