# NORM PPF function pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Code Used:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
from scipy import stats 
from scipy.stats import norm
mylist = [0.083, 0.219, 0.126] 
df = spark.createDataFrame(mylist, FloatType())
df.show() 
norm_ppf = F.udf(lambda x: float(norm.ppf(x)))
df.withColumn("var2", norm_ppf(df['value'])).show()
```

Module scipy is already installed on the system. How do we resolve this issue? Is there any way I can apply norm.ppf function on a column in     pyspark

Error Message:

> /var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py
> in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)        376         """        377
> if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:    --> 378
> print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))        379         else:
> 380             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate),
> vertical))
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in
> **call**(self, *args)       1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)       1256
> return_value = get_return_value(    -> 1257             answer,
> self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)       1258        1259
> for temp_arg in temp_args:
> /var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py
> in deco(*a, **kw)         61     def deco(*a, **kw):         62
> try:    ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)         64
> except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:         65             s =
> e.java_exception.toString()
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in
> get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)        326
> raise Py4JJavaError(        327                     "An error occurred
> while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".    --> 328
> format(target_id, ".", name), value)        329             else:
> 330                 raise Py4JError(        Py4JJavaError: An error
> occurred while calling o2145.showString.    :
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
> Task 0 in stage 19.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
> 0.3 in stage 19.0 (TID 82, d8-td-cdh.boigroup.net, executor 38): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
> call last):      File
> "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
> line 361, in main        func, profiler, deserializer, serializer =
> read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)      File
> "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
> line 236, in read_udfs        arg_offsets, udf =
> read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type, runner_conf)      File
> "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
> line 163, in read_single_udf        f, return_type =
> read_command(pickleSer, infile)      File
> "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
> line 64, in read_command        command =
> serializer._read_with_length(file)      File
> "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
> line 172, in _read_with_length        return self.loads(obj)      File
> "/var/opt/teradata/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
> line 577, in loads        return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'          at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
> at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
> at
> org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
> at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
> at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
> at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown
> Source)       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:624)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)      at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$11.apply(Executor.scala:407)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1363)
> at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:413)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)        Driver stacktrace:
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1890)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
> at
> scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:929)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:929)
> at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)       at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:929)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2111)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2060)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2049)
> at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:740)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2081)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2102)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2121)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3383)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)      at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2544)     at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2758)     at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)       at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)        at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)       at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)      at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)        at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)       at
> py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)        at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)            norm_cdf =
> F.udf(lambda x: float(norm.cdf(x)))        df.withColumn("var2",
> norm_cdf(df['value'])).show()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [probnorm function equivalent in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68496993/probnorm-function-equivalent-in-pyspark). I believe it's the same concept I showed you in a previous question, but instead of using `cdf` you use `ppf`

Comment: I tried below code:from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
from scipy.stats import norm

mylist = [0.083, 0.219, 0.126]
df = spark.createDataFrame(mylist, FloatType())
df.show()
norm_ppf = F.udf(lambda x: float(norm.ppf(x)))
df.withColumn("var2", norm_ppf(df['value'])).show()                                                                 it keeps throwing error....

Comment: Your error says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'`. Are you sure you have installed it? If yes, does it give the same problem as in the other question, i.e. Pyarrow error?

Answer (score 0):

In which spark path you have added scipy library?

As this is pandas library , it wont work in pyspark until you install and add this as external library.

otherwise you need to convert spark to pandas dataframe and apply it. it will work.